# Taking the limit with 2 more variables

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

$\lim_{x\to \infty} (1+a/x)^{bx}$

I came across this question and this is my approach:

$\lim_{x\to \infty}(e^{bx\ln(1+a/x)})$ and I stucked here.

I used calculators to compute the answer and it is $e^{ab}$. Any idea how I can get to the answer? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Theorem 1.** Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a\neq0$. Then
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{a}{x}\right)^{xb} = e^{ab}.$$
*Proof.*
We can extract $b$ from the exponent.
$$\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{a}{x}\right)^{x}\right)^b.$$
We may define
$$L = \lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{a}{x}\right)^x$$
so our final result is equal to $L^b$. Now we will define a new limit variable
$y\cdot a=x$. Since $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a\neq0$ we are alloud to write only the $y\to\infty$ in the limit, because $y\cdot a\to\infty \Rightarrow y\to\infty$.
$$L = \lim_{y\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{a}{ay}\right)^{ay}.$$
**Lemma 2.**
The number $e$ is defined as
$$e = \lim_{y\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right)^{y}.$$
In equation $(4)$ we can cancel the $a$'s and extract the exponent like we did in equation $(2)$. Now we have
$$L=e^a$$
and including $b$ that will give us
$$L^b = e^{ab}.$$ QED

Comment: thank you for your answer. I am not supposed to know the answer (e^ab) as I was asked to calculate using L'Hospital Rule.

Comment: You don't have to know the answer. Also use dollar signs to write mathematical expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

In the limit, $a$ and $b$ are not "variables".

Assuming that $a\ne 0$, the limit can be written as
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left((1+\dfrac{1}{\frac{x}a})^{\frac{x}{a}}\right)^{ab}
=\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}(1+\dfrac{1}{\frac{x}a})^{\frac{x}{a}}\right)^{ab}
$$

Also, depending on the sign of $a$, you will need one of the following limits:
$$
\lim_{y\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1y\right)^y=e,\quad \lim_{y\to-\infty}\left(1+\frac1y\right)^y=e
$$

Comment: I understand the relationship of your equations, but how do I get from my equation to yours?

Comment: @SIMa: edited. Can you combine them now?

Comment: thank you, but i really dont understand... I know im just a step or two away but I still couldnt figure it out...

Comment: i think i got it! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since the exponential is a continuous function, you have that:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{f(x)} = e^{\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)}$$
From there, you should be able to use the Hôpital's rule to evaluate
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} bx \ln(1 + \frac{a}{x})$$ by rewriting
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} bx \ln(1 + \frac{a}{x}) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln(1+\frac{a}{x})}{\frac{1}{bx}}$$ which is of the form $\frac{0}{0}$.

Comment: thank you for your answer. as a new learner, i am confused. could you please show more steps which I can learn from it?